# VSTO - Disable Excel While Async BackgroundWorker is Running

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a VSTO Add-In I am developing for Excel. A form allows a user to query a table from a database and then populates appropriately. 
Bellow is my code for the BackGround Worker, as you can see it runs Async and reports back progress perfectly.

My issue is that while the Process is running, the user is able to manipulate and click in Excel. I know this is the point of asynchronous function but in this case it cause the BackgroundWorker to be interrupted. Is there a way to disable clicks or the active sheet entirely?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //run
    //this.backgroundWorker3.RunWorkerAsync();

    System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker3_ProgressChanged);
    bw.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker3_DoWork);

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();


}

private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker3_WorkerCOmpleted);
    if (!_isExtended)
    {
         oneline ol = new oneline();
         ol.buildOneline(this._wheres,worker );
    }
    else
    {
       ExtendedOneline ole = new ExtendedOneline();
        ole.buildExtendedOneline(this._wheres,worker);
    }
    //worker.ReportProgress();
     e.Result = "COMPLETE!";


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware that multithreading in VSTO is generally not a good idea. However I've had success using a progress dialog ([I started with this one](http://www.parago.de/blog/2011/04/22/how-to-implement-a-modern-progress-dialog-for-wpf-applications.html)). You're still only running one thread that interacts with the API so it's OK as far as I can tell.

You call it like this:

```
ProgressDialogResult result = ProgressDialog.Execute(parent, name, () =>
{
    // do whatever
}, new ProgressDialogSettings(true, true, false));
```

You might also be able to use `WdProtectionType` to disable editing temporarily (this is for Word but I imagine Excel has something similar, maybe XlProtectionType?) but I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply use :

```
 Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlWait

// ... your BackgroundWorker Running here

 Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlDefault;
```

or maybe with:   `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating`